# Get SQL Server stored procedure printed messages in asp.net query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that I run from my ASP.NET website. That stored procedure queries a few tables, make a small calculation, and then select a table containing results, which in ASP.NET I put inside a DataTable.

In that stored procedure I also print messages for debugging purposes using the SQL PRINT command.

What I would like to do, is in my ASP.NET code when I call the stored procedure, also get the messages it printed out (so I can save it to a file).

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the answer you are looking for is here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e67cb4e-196e-4992-b9ab-8809073ea856/net-sql-client-and-tsql-print-commands?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: thanks. is there a code example to setting the properties he's talking about?

Comment: The SqlConnection object should have an InfoMessage event, you want to listen to that event, the event should be fired after the procedure is executed.